# Prerequisites for Measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I studied computer science and i had all the mendatory math courses such as:
Calculus ,Linear algebra,Probability,Set theory,Combinatorics

But I didnt take any advanced course in mathematical analysis or topology. 
Does the knowledge I have is sufficent to study measure theory?

Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly advise taking analysis before measure theory.  I can't believe it isn't a prerequisite.  Or if this is self-study, do analysis first.    You'll learn some topology in analysis, and it might be enough for measure theory, depending on how deeply you get into it.

Comment: Depends, are you self-studying or taking a course at a university? In the latter case you'd better take up this question with the professor/assistent of the course.

Comment: The answer to your question depends in part on why you need to know measure theory. If it's for general ideas, or perhaps an application, you might be able to start trying to learn it and fill in what you can't follow. For an in depth study you should probably have a real analysis course first, or at least a rigorous calculus/advanced calculus course that stressed proofs.

Comment: Thanks. Im going to study by myself for practical purposes. I studied calclus 1 (for R) and 2 (for R^n). But i dont know concepts like metric space, open sets and etc. What kind of analysis you recommend? Numerical? Functional? Other?

Comment: At least a bit of topology (metric space, open sets,...) and if you can study Functional analysis it can be a good complement (since a way to build the theory of integration is to use Radon Measure, which are functionals over spaces of functions, so there is a interesting bridge between measure theory and functional analysis ; but it is not mandatory , you can learn first directly measure theory, of course).